# Floating point exception when loading LD_PRELOAD libstdc++.so.6 and libc.so.6 from new and different distribution

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, g++, debian

I have application compiled on rather NEW ubunto distribution (kernel 3.2.0-53-virtual) using g++ 4.7.2. After compilation completes (and works on this machine), I'm taking the products to OLD Debian 4 distribution  (kernel 2.6.34.10). I currently CANNOT change distribution. I'm trying to run the application and get:

> Bin/MY_APP: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by Bin/MY_APP)
>   Bin/MY_APP: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version`GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by Bin/MY_APP)
>   Bin/MY_APP: /lib/tls/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by Bin/MY_APP)
>   Bin/MY_APP: /lib/tls/libc.so.6: version`GLIBC_2.11' not found (required by Bin/MY_APP)
>   Bin/MY_APP: /lib/tls/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.4' not found (required by Bin/MY_APP)
>   Bin/MY_APP: /lib/tls/libc.so.6: version`GLIBC_2.12' not found (required by Bin/MY_APP)
>   Bin/MY_APP: /lib/tls/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.7' not found (required by Bin/MY_APP)

I tried to solve the issue, and took from the machine I compiled the application (NEW ubunto) libstdc++.so.6 & libc.so.6 and put them on /usr/lib/MY_APP_LIB/ , but when I run:

> env LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/MY_APP_LIB/libstdc++.so.6:/usr/lib/MY_APP_LIB/libc.so.6  /opt/MY_APP/MY_appp

I get:

> Floating point exception

even if I run ls or any linux command:

> env LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/MY_APP_LIB/libstdc++.so.6:/usr/lib/MY_APP_LIB/libc.so.6  ls

I get the "Floating point exception"

of course also when I try to point LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the /usr/lib/MY_APP_LIB same result.

dmesg shows:

> Process 394(MY_APP) has RLIMIT_CORE set to 0
>   Aborting core
>   Process 422(ls) has RLIMIT_CORE set to 0
>   Aborting core

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This problem may happens because you change libc.so.6 library. simple solution you can try to set LD_PRELOAD flag to its previous libc.so.6 path. for ex

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/lib/libc.so.6:$LD_PRELOAD
ldconfig
```